# SQL - date column automatically changing each time I update table

Tags: sql

I have a `date` column in my table. When I perform an `update` query on the rows, each time the `date` gets refreshed to the current date. I have set date's default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but why is this happening each time?

**UPDATE**

My create query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `ACCOUNTS` (
  `id` bigint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1234567 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: please show your update query.

Comment: Also the code that creates the table might be helpful.

Comment: You don't happen to have any weird `AFTER UPDATE` triggers on the table do you?

Comment: my update query was very simple `update ACCOUNTS set name='somename' where id='1234'` it had nothing to do with `date` column

Comment: I just tried it myself and the behavior was as expected. the timestamp didn't changed. Please also post the create sql of your table so I can examine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably something to do with `date` being a keyword. try changing it to `some_date`. Was `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` intentional?

Comment: I dont have an explanation myself, but I had this same issue once. Wasted a lot of time on it :)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, sql will insert the current time stamp at the time of creating new record only and will never update it unless you update it yourself. Refreshing will not update the timestamp

Comment: apparently, it will refresh the date each time you update the table. refer to my answer below. i remember facing this problem once

Comment: Please post your query, so I can help with it - Your update query should be doing something that is causing such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use a MariaDB, this documentation page https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/timestamp/ may have some surprising information for you:

> "The timestamp field is generally used to define at which moment in time a row was added or updated and by default **will automatically be assigned the current datetime when a record is inserted or updated**. The automatic properties only apply to the first TIMESTAMP in the record; subsequent TIMESTAMP columns will not be changed."

Hope this bit helps the next developer who runs into this fantastic feature...